# Error creating bean with name 'newsController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is

Tags: java, spring, api, rest

Изучаю spring rest

Сделал авторизацию, к ней решил сделать ответ сервера содержимого таблицы
Не пойму что ему не нравится

UserServiceImpl:

```
@Component("userService")
@Scope("session")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    private boolean logined;

    @Autowired
    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }


    public boolean login(String name, String password)
    {
        User user = userRepository.findOne(name);
        if(user == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        boolean result =  user.getPassword().equals(password);
        logined = result;
        return logined;
    }

    public void logout()
    {
        logined = false;
    }

    public boolean isLogined() {
        return logined;
    }
}
```

UserService:

```
public interface UserService {

    boolean login(String name, String password);

    void logout();

    boolean isLogined();
}
```

UserRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User,String>
{


}
```

NewsRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface NewsRepository extends CrudRepository<News, String> {

    List<News> findAllNews();

}
```

User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {


    @Id
    private String name;

    private String password;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

News:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "news")
public class News {

    private long id;
    private String title;
    private String text;

    @Id
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

При создании `newsController`a в нем я так понял и возникает ошибка

```
@RestController
public class NewsController {

    @Autowired
    private NewsRepository rep;

    @RequestMapping("/news")
    public @ResponseBody
    java.util.List<News> index()
    {
        return rep.findAllNews();
    }

}
```

Из за того что тут есть  Autowired

```
@RestController
@Scope("session")
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping("/**")
    public Object index()
    {
        return new Error("no access");
    }

    @RequestMapping("/rest/login")
    public Object login(@RequestParam("username") String username, @RequestParam("password") String password) {

        String response;

        if(userService.login(username, password))
        {
            response = Utitlity.constructJSON("login",true);
            return response;
        }
        return new Error("auth failed");
    }

    @RequestMapping("/rest/logout")
    public Object logout() {

        if(!userService.isLogined()){
            return new Error("no logined");
        }
        userService.logout();
        return new Response("loggedout");
    }
}
```

Comment: Приведи полный трейс ошибки + spring-конфигурацию приложения. Также неплохо указывать классы с именами пакетов, в которых они лежат.